# How to animate cutting/splitting?

Tags: animation

I created a grid, rising mountains by using displace modifier with texture as below. [image]

I want to create an animation to cut it into below. and then show its cut-surface.

[image]

The following image shows the final result I expect

[image]

[image]

Comment: hello could you please tell a bit more about the animation you want? also maybe share your object? (pack the image that you're using)

Comment: @moonboots, I want to split the model into two parts, and animate them by moving one part away.   there is no image, the texture is from blender itself.  I don't know how to share the blend file here.

Comment: read the instructions here: https://blend-exchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use 3 objects: Your original plane, and 2 duplications that each has its own boolean (intersect) object (I've pushed all the objects apart to see them individually but of course they are overlapping):

[image]

Only object 1 is visible at the beginning, when you want to slice your object, make object 1 invisible and make objects 2 and 3 visible. To keyframe the visibility, go into the *Object* panel > *Visibility > Show In*:

[image]

Comment: thank you @moonboots,  I converted the grid into mesh,  and using boolean modifier to combine a cube and this new mesh,  it does not work. I have updated the question with blender file.